#  using Python to retrieve missing sequences -'split' command does not work

Tags: python, split, biopython

I have a set of (protein)sequences that has been found using a software but they are shorter in length than that of the original ones in the database.I downloaded the entire database ,and now i have these set of incomplete sequences that have been found and the original database from which the sequences have been found.

Example result from software:

```
>tr|E7EWP2|E7EWP2_HUMAN  Uncharacterized protein OS=Homo sapiens GN=TRIO PE=4 SV=2
KEFIMAELIQTEKAYVRDLRECMDTYLWEMTSGVE
```

Sequence in the database:

```
>tr|E7EWP2|E7EWP2_HUMAN  Uncharacterized protein OS=Homo sapiens GN=TRIO PE=4 SV=2
ARRKEFIMAELIQTEKAYVRDLRECMDTYLWEMTSGVEEIP
```

So the missing residues are 'ARR' and in the end 'EIP', I have around 70 incomplete  sequences like this? I would like to write a Python program that can automatically retrieve the complete sequences from the database.
I am really new to python ,ofcourse i will try to write my own code ,i would like to know if there are any libraries or something like biopython modules that can do this.
 My plan is to take the intervals from my result,expand them and select it on the original database,but i do not know how to proceed further.

i would like to get `list_seq = [ARR,KEFIMAELIQTEKAYVRDLRECMDTYLWEMTSGVE,EIP]` so that i can further use `list_seq[0] r.strip(3)` and `list_seq[1] l.strip[3]` so that i get the complete sequence. but list_seq does not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cool story, now get to work and come back when you have a specific  programming problem.

Comment: What Jochen wants to communicate is that the question is of the kind "write this program for me" which is not the purpose of this web site. You have good chances to get help if you show your own efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: You might want to look at [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html).

Comment: sorry my question was not to ask someone to write the code but to get some helpful suggestions as to how to approach this,sorry if my question meant otherwise,i have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Please, try `"abcdef".split('cd')` and you will see why *your part of the code* is not working as you want. If you want to get profit of `helpful suggestions` and not `someone to write the code` you should start from some good tutorial (there are plenty in the web).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `index` method from BioPython SeqIO. The `index` method indexes database records by  protein `id` and doesn't load the full database in memory thus allowing efficient search with complete, big databases (alternatively you could use a conventional dbase like sqlite to first store your records and perform searches on it):

```
from Bio import SeqIO

db1 = "dbase.fasta"
db2 = "my_collection.fasta"

dbase_dict = SeqIO.index(db1, "fasta")
my_record_dict = SeqIO.index(db2, "fasta")

for record in my_record_dict:
    if record in dbase_dict:
        rec_dbase = dbase_dict[record]
        rec_mine = my_record_dict[record]
        if rec_dbase.seq != rec_mine.seq:
            print rec_dbase
```

This program just print the records with differences. From this point you can save them on a list or write to a fasta file

Comment: i would like to split my sequence from the dbase that is  list_seq = rec_dbase.seq.split("rec_mine.seq"),and but i do not know why it does not work?

Comment: @hari, select the answer if it answered your first question before asking for a new, completely different thing. On the other hand, it would be more clear if you rollback your question text to its original state and ask for the new problem in a different Post.